# Go package is installed when i instsall AWS Sam cli

Tags: go, ubuntu, aws-sam-cli

i added aws-sam-cli installation in the dockerfile, and when it is built and scanned for vulnerability, it picks up go version 1.16.4. when i run go --version, it says command not found and I'm having trouble finding where go binary is located so I can remove.

Has anyone ran into this same issue?

Comment: Please share further details; it's not really clear what you mean by "aws-sam-cli installation in the dockerfile" so please include the `dockerfile` in your question (that way we can see exactly what you are doing), also providing the full vulnerability report would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed `https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/releases/download/v1.81.0/aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip` in a container, and it does not cause Go to be installed.

If in doubt, you can examine the content of the image yourself. It can tell you whether the image contains the target file or not; and if it contains the target file, it can tell you it's added to which layer.

#### Examine the content of a docker image

Let's use the image `golang:1.18.4-alpine3.16` as an example. Follow these steps:

```
$ mkdir check-image && cd check-image
$ docker save -o go-image.tar golang:1.18.4-alpine3.16
$ tar xvf go-image.tar
$ tree
.
├── 00179bf748629c3484345111d5de49224b12ff9b2d1883ae14e1f17b14e9f7b8
│   ├── json
│   ├── layer.tar
│   └── VERSION
├── 0831657d5ac7ff942f3425dab50e05cf8c74656d5353a989eb5ce91b8cdf2af9
│   ├── json
│   ├── layer.tar
│   └── VERSION
├── 4b29fa21f075df9e359b67f428cbf1f57d92a74a27b97de9a2af031e2bd145aa
│   ├── json
│   ├── layer.tar
│   └── VERSION
├── 4e306bbd9ffb25249738ad9a165c09a7433b72e450a771234d457cd6fd377b16
│   ├── json
│   ├── layer.tar
│   └── VERSION
├── 759ab1463be285f7f2c9a5a817cc0b1fdc5352e38be51d8cc0895b0c29a547de.json
├── c759d8dd0dbd2e3d7a81f911e75aab009e10e26abbc3d8c6b86cf4b1f43a6b58
│   ├── json
│   ├── layer.tar
│   └── VERSION
├── go-image.tar
├── manifest.json
└── repositories
$ i=1 && jq -r '.[] | .Layers[] | .' manifest.json | while read -r layer; do echo "layer $i: $layer" && ((i++)) && tar tvf $layer | grep -E '/go$'; done
layer 1: c759d8dd0dbd2e3d7a81f911e75aab009e10e26abbc3d8c6b86cf4b1f43a6b58/layer.tar
layer 2: 4b29fa21f075df9e359b67f428cbf1f57d92a74a27b97de9a2af031e2bd145aa/layer.tar
layer 3: 0831657d5ac7ff942f3425dab50e05cf8c74656d5353a989eb5ce91b8cdf2af9/layer.tar
layer 4: 00179bf748629c3484345111d5de49224b12ff9b2d1883ae14e1f17b14e9f7b8/layer.tar
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0        14546854 2022-07-19 07:00 usr/local/go/bin/go
layer 5: 4e306bbd9ffb25249738ad9a165c09a7433b72e450a771234d457cd6fd377b16/layer.tar

$ jq '.history | map(select(.empty_layer|not)) as $layers | $layers | range(length) | {layer: (.+1)} + $layers[.]' ?????????*.json

{
  "layer": 1,
  "created": "2022-07-18T21:00:15.800417218Z",
  "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:a2648378045615c3785c752423b1afc8dc1c2b213393344f4d0ca17e7255c1cb in / "
}
{
  "layer": 2,
  "created": "2022-07-18T22:56:26.275665468Z",
  "created_by": "/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache ca-certificates"
}
{
  "layer": 3,
  "created": "2022-07-18T22:56:26.911341435Z",
  "created_by": "/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /etc/nsswitch.conf ] && echo 'hosts: files dns' > /etc/nsswitch.conf"
}
{
  "layer": 4,
  "created": "2022-07-18T23:00:06.068412151Z",
  "created_by": "/bin/sh -c set -eux; \tapk add --no-cache --virtual .fetch-deps gnupg; \tarch=\"$(apk --print-arch)\"; \turl=; \tcase \"$arch\" in \t\t'x86_64') \t\t\texport GOAMD64='v1' GOARCH='amd64' GOOS='linux'; \t\t\t;; \t\t'armhf') \t\t\texport GOARCH='arm' GOARM='6' GOOS='linux'; \t\t\t;; \t\t'armv7') \t\t\texport GOARCH='arm' GOARM='7' GOOS='linux'; \t\t\t;; \t\t'aarch64') \t\t\texport GOARCH='arm64' GOOS='linux'; \t\t\t;; \t\t'x86') \t\t\texport GO386='softfloat' GOARCH='386' GOOS='linux'; \t\t\t;; \t\t'ppc64le') \t\t\texport GOARCH='ppc64le' GOOS='linux'; \t\t\t;; \t\t's390x') \t\t\texport GOARCH='s390x' GOOS='linux'; \t\t\t;; \t\t*) echo >&2 \"error: unsupported architecture '$arch' (likely packaging update needed)\"; exit 1 ;; \tesac; \tbuild=; \tif [ -z \"$url\" ]; then \t\tbuild=1; \t\turl='https://dl.google.com/go/go1.18.4.src.tar.gz'; \t\tsha256='4525aa6b0e3cecb57845f4060a7075aafc9ab752bb7b6b4cf8a212d43078e1e4'; \tfi; \t\twget -O go.tgz.asc \"$url.asc\"; \twget -O go.tgz \"$url\"; \techo \"$sha256 *go.tgz\" | sha256sum -c -; \t\tGNUPGHOME=\"$(mktemp -d)\"; export GNUPGHOME; \tgpg --batch --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 'EB4C 1BFD 4F04 2F6D DDCC  EC91 7721 F63B D38B 4796'; \tgpg --batch --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys '2F52 8D36 D67B 69ED F998  D857 78BD 6547 3CB3 BD13'; \tgpg --batch --verify go.tgz.asc go.tgz; \tgpgconf --kill all; \trm -rf \"$GNUPGHOME\" go.tgz.asc; \t\ttar -C /usr/local -xzf go.tgz; \trm go.tgz; \t\tif [ -n \"$build\" ]; then \t\tapk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \t\t\tbash \t\t\tgcc \t\t\tgo \t\t\tmusl-dev \t\t; \t\t\t\texport GOCACHE='/tmp/gocache'; \t\t\t\t( \t\t\tcd /usr/local/go/src; \t\t\texport GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=\"$(go env GOROOT)\" GOHOSTOS=\"$GOOS\" GOHOSTARCH=\"$GOARCH\"; \t\t\t./make.bash; \t\t); \t\t\t\tapk del --no-network .build-deps; \t\t\t\trm -rf \t\t\t/usr/local/go/pkg/*/cmd \t\t\t/usr/local/go/pkg/bootstrap \t\t\t/usr/local/go/pkg/obj \t\t\t/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/*/api \t\t\t/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/*/go_bootstrap \t\t\t/usr/local/go/src/cmd/dist/dist \t\t\t\"$GOCACHE\" \t\t; \tfi; \t\tapk del --no-network .fetch-deps; \t\tgo version"
}
{
  "layer": 5,
  "created": "2022-07-18T23:00:07.911497908Z",
  "created_by": "/bin/sh -c mkdir -p \"$GOPATH/src\" \"$GOPATH/bin\" && chmod -R 777 \"$GOPATH\""
}
```

#### Highlight

1. Use `docker image save` to save an image to a tar archive.
2. The archive contains meta data and archives for each laryer.
3. Use `tar tvf [layer_archive] | grep -E '/go$'` to search the `go` binary in a layer archive.
4. We found the `go` binary in the fourth non-empty layer which is created by `/bin/sh -c set -eux; \tapk add --no-cache --virtual .fetch-deps gnupg;...`.
5. `?????????*.json` matches the json file in the current directory whose name contains at least 9 characters (to exclude `manifest.json`, and it's `759ab1463be285f7f2c9a5a817cc0b1fdc5352e38be51d8cc0895b0c29a547de.json` in our example). This file contains the layer history.